# XPath expression for finding descendents with attribute but not any descendants of those descendants

Tags: html, xml, xpath

I am trying to find an **XPath expression** that **selects all descendants** of an element with a certain attribute, **but not any of the descendants of those elements** with that attribute.

To show what I mean, here's an example:

```
<div element-id="1" data-type="TreeView">
    <div element-id="2" data-type=Border">
        <div element-id="3" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Shapes">
            <div element-id="4" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Triagles">
                <div delement-id="5" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Isosceles"></div>
            </div>
            <div element-id="6" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Quadrilaterals">
                <div element-id="7" data-type=Border">
                    <div element-id="8" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Square"></div>
                    <div element-id="9" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Rectangle"></div>
                    <div element-id="10" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Rhombus"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div element-id="12" data-type="TreeViewItem" data-value="Pentagons">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

If I were to use the desired search expression on the above html, with the element 1 ('element-id' equals '1') being the current element, and searching for all descendants where 'data-type' equals 'TreeViewItem'. Then the expression would return only element 3.

There are other elements where 'data-type' equals 'TreeViewItem' but since they're all descendants of element 3, they would be excluded from the search results.

Another example is if element 3 were the current element, and searching all descendants with the desired expression where 'data-type' equals 'TreeViewItem', then elements 4, 6, and 12 would be returned. But none of their descendants would be.

Also an **important distinction**. The elements are not necessarily direct children of the current search elment. Which is why it's important to search for descendants and not direct children.

Currently what I have for an XPath expression is:

```
.//div[@data-type='TreeViewItem']
```

But this returns all descendants with that attribute. And I'm not sure how to exclude descendants of the descendants that already have that attribute.

So if someone could help me finish this expression, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Which are the expected elements on the first use case?

Comment: @LuisMuñoz the only expected element is element 3.